# 'apksigner' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. In Ionic v3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying build ionic android app using this [Deploying to a Device](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/)

but showing error when i run this commend: apksigner verify HelloWorld.apk

Error:

```
D:\ionic\demoAds1>apksigner verify HelloWorld.apk
'apksigner' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\ionic\demoAds1>
```

Any Idea what to do?

Comment: Hello sir, i want verify android app using above ionic commend but coming this error "'apksigner' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Did you see this https://www.clemdesign.fr/en/blog/ionic-3-fix-warnings-about-version-files-in-meta-inf-of-apk-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running apksigner from the SDK build tools folder inside the folder where your Android SDK was installed:

```
D:\PATH-TO-ANDROID-SDK\build-tools\VERSION-NUMBER\apksigner.exe verify HelloWorld.apk
```

Also make sure that you are running the latest version of the build tools.

Answer (score 1):

When I always try to sign and app I go to this page it has a few steps to do that sign with key tool and jarsigner

[sign app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html)